# How to map a keybinding to a command which includes <C-U> (scroll-up) in my .vimrc?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

I want to map a keybinding to a command which includes `<C-U>` not for clearing the command line but for scrolling the page up. Executing a command like this in my vim session works totally fine:

```
:exe "normal \<C-U>"
```

But when I try to map something to the exact same command in my `.vimrc`, it doesn't work:

```
" My .vimrc
nnoremap <leader>u :exe "normal \<C-U>"<CR>
```

Now when I do `<leader>u` it leaves `:"` in my status bar which indicates `<C-U>` is clearing the line instead of scrolling the page. What is the problem?

---

**Edit:** I oversimplified the keybinding that I'm actually using to only point to what causes the problem and avoid confusion. I am using `<C-U>` in the context of a much more complicated keybinding but I need it to mean "scroll-up" instead of "clear the line."  I'm using this binding `nnoremap <leader>wu :<C-U>call win_execute(win_getid(winnr('#')), ":exe 'normal \<C-U>'")<CR>` to scroll another window without switching directly to it. I already used it with `<C-D>` for scrolling down and it works perfectly fine but this one doesn't work because of the other meaning that `<C-U>` has in command mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so: I am having a remarkably hard time finding the section of the documentation that discusses how the right-hand-side of a mapping is interpreted (i.e., how the keycodes are read during `:map` and then later used upon execution). What I did discover with some trial-and-error, though, is this:

1. `nnoremap ... :execute "normal! <C-u>"<CR>` has a literal `<C-u>` already in it, so that's why that fails. This happens even with the backslash, I think because `nnoremap` processes the `<C-u>` before execute/normal/double-quotes ever get to it.
2. To work around that, we need to escape the `<` using `<lt>`. However, then we have the mapping running `:execute "normal! <C-u>"` which already doesn't work.
3. To get around that, we need to put a backslash back into the string; for some reason, I couldn't make `\\` work, even though that is supposed too—I may have needed to double (`\\\\`), but I didn't want to do that. So, I used `<Bslash>`.

The final mapping is

```
nnoremap ... :execute "normal! <Bslash><lt>C-u>"<CR>
```

Phew

P.S. I was able to work through this by reading the output of `:map {rhs}` and realizing what characters had been pre-processed and what hadn't, as well as actually running the mapping to see what had happened.

P.P.S. I still don't think these shenanigans should be necessary for `win_execute`; it should be sufficient to pass the `normal!` command directly (with some pre-escaping if it's in a mapping). For example,

```
call win_execute(win_getid(winnr()), "normal! \<C-u>")
```

worked for me. You would probably need to use `<Bslash>` and `<lt>C-u>` in the mapping version.

Comment: Wow! The level of effort you put into it is just heroic. Even though it's advised to not send comments to thank someone, I found it unfair not to! So thanks so much.

Comment: @SaeedAhadian helping you is thanks enough; and the rep helps :P youre very welcome. I’m just glad for this community in so many ways, and I want to see it thrive. I think I’m going to clean up pur comment convo and move some info into your question for posterity.